# UITextInput: selectedTextRange vs. markedTextRange?

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols, uitextinput, uitextrange

Ok, so I know Apple's `UITextInput` protocol requires the two `UITextRange` properties `selectedTextRange` and `markedTextRange` and the documentation says that `selectedTextRange` is a subrange of `markedTextRange` which is an uncomfirmed text range by the user yatta yatta. That still doesn't make some things clear to me regarding how  I ought to implement the two text ranges differently. Could someone visually explain to me the difference between `selectedTextRange` and `markedTextRange`? I know that when the `length` of `selectedTextRange` is `0` it indicates a blinking caret at `selectedTextRange`'s `location`. But what the heck is "marked text"?? I've only seen the following for text views in iOS:

[image: example of <code>selectedTextRange</code>]

Which I assume represents the current `selectedTextRange`. What does `markedTextRange` look like? Or is it basically the exact same thing? I'm so confused :( Thanks in advance for any help! The documentation has proven itself useless in my understanding of how to implement the `UITextInput` protocol.

**EDIT**

Does implementing `markedTextRange` have anything to do with the fact that some text in a view could be "markable" but "readonly" and `selectedTextRange` indicates the subrange in  the "marked text", `markedTextRange`, that is readwrite?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From Apple documentation for `UITextInput`:

> Marked text, which is part of multistage text input, represents provisionally 
>   inserted text that the user has yet to confirm. It is styled in a distinctive 
>   way. The range of marked text always contains within it a range of selected 
>   text, which might be a range of characters or the caret.

Hence `markedTextRange` gets useful with languages that requires multistage input, e.g. Japanese.
In simple words: what user types is yet to be confirmed before it can be added to the value of the text input control is were `markedTextRange` gets into the game. GIF bellow demonstrates `markedTextRange` in action:

[image]

Notice slight sapphire background behind the unconfirmed hieroglyphs. Once text gets confirmed either by hitting enter/return, selecting option from suggestions or finger tap on text area after the marked text gets added to the input control value and background gets removed.

**Notes:**

- markedTextRange has nothing to do with read-only text
- I was not able to achieve multiple symbols selection within markedTextRange

Comment: Can you advise how to properly limit max text input length? i.e. if i limit input to 3 chars and try to input "ででで" which is achieved when i press keyboard buttons "dedede"(each "de" transforms into "で") then i am not able to input the last character, because my validation function considers that to be 4 characters. Here is my validation function: `-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField*)tf shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)r replacementString:(NSString*)s {return [tf.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:s].length <= 3;}` This can be reproduced on `Japanese - Romaji` keyboard

Comment: i mean, i could still use a completion `popup` sticked to top of a keyboard, but that seems like a workaround.. or am i overlooking this..?

Comment: @igrek consider always returning true in case `textField.markedTextRange != nil`

Comment: with regards to `e.g. Japanese` -- the mutlistage input is also important to support for any language which has autocorrect behavior going on. Try to type `trst` in a message field for example, probably the text will "marked" and replaced on space bar