# Detect keyboard combinations that change text

Tags: ios, swift4, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have a library I’m building that needs to keep track of text entry into a UITextView in order to keep track of positions of certain sections of text. Most cases are handled fine within the `textView(_:shouldChangeTextIn:replacementText:)` method. The problem I’m having is that certain keyboards have character combinations that will actually change the character without calling the `textView(_:shouldChangeTextIn:replacementText:)` method. A simple example of this is if you choose a Vietnamese keyboard and type `uw` it will change to `ú` but the only calls to `textView(_:shouldChangeTextIn:replacementText:)` will be for the entry of u and w. The offset calculations will be incorrect at this point. As far as I can tell there’s no other method that I could use to know about this change. I’m not sure if this is a bug or not. The textViewDidChange method will be called but I was hoping to avoid hacky logic where I compare the previous and new text of the textView to determine any changes and adjust logic there. If anyone has suggestions I would love to hear them. Hopefully someone has seen and solved this problem. Thanks.

To clarify, I need to handle this situation using something other than subclassing.

Sample project: https://github.com/szweier/ShouldChangeTextInRange
If you run the code above and choose the Vietnamese keyboard to type in `uw` you will see that the string generated in the `textView(_:shouldChangeTextIn:replacementText:)` method will be different from the text within the textView.

Answer (score 0):

`UITextView` or it's delegate doesn't have a `shouldReplaceCharacters` API as far as I know (and I'm not googling up anything useful either, at least for iOS -- [it does exist for macOS though](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextfinderclient/1529811-shouldreplacecharacters))

If I subclass `UITextView`, I can override `insertText` and detect what the true insertion point is:

```
class TestTextView : UITextView {
    override func insertText(_ text: String) {

        let selectedRange = self.selectedRange
        if let markedRange = self.markedTextRange {
            Swift.print("TestTextView inserting \(text) at \(selectedRange.location) & \(selectedRange.length) ; marked = \(markedRange.start) & \(markedRange.end)")
        } else {
            Swift.print("TestTextView inserting \(text) at \(selectedRange.location) & \(selectedRange.length) and no marked range")
        }
        super.insertText(text)
    }
}
```

When I add this subclassed `TestTextView` to a test project and turn on a VN keyboard.  Here's what I see for `uw` typed in:

```
TestTextView inserting u at 17 & 0 and no marked range
TestTextView inserting ư at 17 & 0 and no marked range
```

while "e" & "b" typed sequentially looks like this:

```
TestTextView inserting e at 17 & 0 and no marked range
TestTextView inserting b at 18 & 0 and no marked range
```

[image: My Test Project UI looks like this]

Lastly, my answer is pretty simple and you may need to [keep track of "marked text range", which comes into play with this multistage text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24632708/uitextinput-selectedtextrange-vs-markedtextrange).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry if I didn’t get the delegate method name exact (I was typing from my phone and didn’t double check exact naming I meant https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618630-textview . In any case for my situation I can’t subclass I’ve created a class that inserts itself as the delegate for the UITextView. I apologize for having not made that clear above.

Comment: What's your technical limitation for not being able to subclass?  Subclasses of UITextView can still designate a `UITextViewDelegate` and use its protocol.

Comment: I’m building an open sourced library that handles the addition/deletion of mentions into a textView. I avoided making it a subclass in order to provide more freedom to the user of the library. If they wanted to use, for example, a placeholder textView library that was a subclass of UITextView I wanted my library to remain usable. For what it’s worth the library is also essentially done and this was an issue that was reported recently. Refactoring into a subclass isn’t something I’m prepared to do either way.

Comment: You could try [method](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/method-swizzling-in-ios-swift-1f38edaf984f) [swizzling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562887/how-to-implement-method-swizzling-swift-3-0) `UITextView`'s `insertText`.

Comment: Good point. I was just rereading your original solution and I’m wondering if the data received is correct. In the case where we insert u and then ú it seems to be saying it inserted u at position 17 with a length of 0 and the same for ú in that case, assuming I’m reading this properly, it’s saying that the end result is `”some text úu”` I would think the second insert log would say at 17 & 1 in order to replace. Am I wrong? It seems like none of these methods get quite enough information in this scenario.

Comment: I added a sample project that seems to show the issue relatively clearly. I've also created a bug report for Apple although I'm not sure whether or not my expectation of having that method called when the OS makes the replacement is a valid expectation. The docs seem to say it's only called upon user text entry.